# How to handle zxing if not installed on Device?

Tags: android, zxing

I'm developing an app that has QR code reading ability, i'm using the Zxing library, launching via intent, so the Barcode Scanner is handling the QR reading functionality, my question is, if the user doesnt have the Barcode Scanner App installed on their device, is there a way to bring them to the app store to get the application for their device?

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the [ZXing `IntentIntegrator`](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent), which will automatically give the user the option to visit the Play Store if the app is not installed on their device.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing) using `IntentIntegrator`, including a JAR edition of that class (in the project's `libs/` directory).